# Query string error: Undefined index: id

Tags: php

I am using a query string code. I want to "get" variable of one page to another page.

query1.php:

```
<?php
$konek = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("test",$konek) or die("Cannot connect to the database");
$query = mysql_query("select * from persons where id='1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$q= $row['details'];
?>

<a href='query_1.php?id=" . $q . "'>aa</a>
```

query_1.php:

```
<?php
//$ab=1;

//if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
$ab= $_GET['id'];
echo $ab;
?>
```

The above code does not run and give error:

Notice: Undefined index: id

I am not geting what i am missing.
So, can some help me out wid my mistake....

Comment: <a href=>>'<<query_1.php?id=>>"<< . $q . "'>aa</a>  + php tags to print the variable $q not the string **" . $q . "**

Comment: Does it produce correct link in `<a href='query_1.php?id=" . $q . "'>aa</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to echo the variable:

`<a href='query_1.php?id="<?php echo $q; ?>"'>aa</a>`

and your done :)

Better use the object oriented form of mysqli in the future.

Answer (score 5):

HTML will not understand that you're using a PHP variable,

```
<a href='query_1.php?id="<?php echo $q; ?>"'>aa</a>
```

**Warning:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

You can not use php variable inside html without php tag.
replace this:

```
<a href='query_1.php?id=" . $q . "'>aa</a>
```

by this:

```
<a href="query_1.php?id=<?php echo $q; ?>">aa</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is passing `$q` in your `<a>` tag. Do this:

```
<a href='query_1.php?id=<?php echo $q;?>'>aa</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but mysql_fetch_array() retrieves a whole array. You only want a single result, which should be retrieved by using mysql_fetch_row().

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mysqli because mysql is [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)